# Saving Excel workbook as HTML - Cannot access 'System.IO.MemoryStream'

Tags: c#, excel, .net

I have some code that i want to convert an excel spread sheet to `html` so i can use it as the body of a email.

```
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Properties.Settings.Default.FileToSend);

        //Save the workbook to Memory Stream in HTML format
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        // This is the line i have an error on
        workbook.SaveAs(ms, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlHtml); 

        //Seek MemoryStream position to 0
        ms.Position = 0;

        //Define a StreamReader object with the above MemoryStream
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);

        //Load the saved HTML from StreamReader now into a string variable
        string strHtmlBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

This is the line i get the error on

```
        // This is the line i have an error on
        workbook.SaveAs(ms, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlHtml);
```

I get this error `Cannot access 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.`

The exception is

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
HelpLink=xlmain11.chm
HResult=-2146827284
Message=Cannot access 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.
Source=Microsoft Excel
ErrorCode=-2146827284
StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.SaveAs(Object Filename, Object FileFormat, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object ReadOnlyRecommended, Object  \ CreateBackup, XlSaveAsAccessMode AccessMode, Object ConflictResolution, Object AddToMru, Object TextCodepage, Object TextVisualLayout, Object Local)
   at Auto_KPI_Email.Program.sendExcel() in E:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Auto KPI Email\Auto KPI Email\Program.cs:line 71
   at Auto_KPI_Email.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Auto KPI Email\Auto KPI Email\Program.cs:line 19
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

Any advice?

Comment: What is the full exception message and stack trace? What line of your code is causing the error?

Comment: Do you mind paste the complete exception as well?

Comment: OK, I have added the exception detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@GrantWinney pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22162667/73025), you cannot save a workbook to a `MemoryStream` using the available API.

Your best solution is to output the HTML to a temporary location and then read the result back in.

```
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Properties.Settings.Default.FileToSend);

var temporaryFilepath = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), ".html");
workbook.SaveAs(temporaryFilepath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlHtml);

var result = File.ReadAllText(temporaryFilepath);
```

Not as elegant as keeping it in memory, however when integrating with other programs it is sometimes the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.saveas.aspx), and the stacktrace you posted, the first parameter is a file name (string). The reason it accepts your MemoryStream  *(or anything else you feel like passing to it)* is because the parameter type is an object. At runtime though, it expects a string.

> *Filename* Optional Object. A string that indicates the name of the file to be saved. You can include a full path; if you don't, Microsoft Excel saves the file in the current folder.

I don't see any parameter in that `SaveAs` method that would accept a stream. Looks like if you want to save your workbook, you'll have to save it to disk.

Comment: OK, So is there a different way to get the Content of an spreadsheet and use it as the body of an email?

Comment: @Ja77aman, as Winney mentioned, you are unable to do it in this way. If you are keen to save it to memorystream, it is better you take a look at some third-party libraries, such as GemBox.Spreadsheet