# .net Save excel file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, memorystream

I do not understand what is the problem, I am reading excel file from upload folder and then I want to update the file and save it as new xlxs file

> Error Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot access 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Contactless.xls"));
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "will test sheet";
using (var stream  = new MemoryStream())
{
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(stream);
    var content = stream.ToArray();
    return File(content,
         "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument-spreadsheetml.sheet",
         "contactless.xlsx");

}
```

Comment: It is ok not understanding the cause of a problem, but you should provide details of the error or the wrong behavior

Comment: xlWorkBook.SaveAs(stream); Cannot access 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.

Comment: Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot access 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/22162475/120955

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clean the InteropServices in end.

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFile);
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "will test sheet";

           
            xlWorkBook.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();

            // CLEAN UP.
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
```